# How to map multiple mouse buttons to the same action?

Tags: mouse

I have a trackball and added two buttons to the device (seen as button 8 and 9).  I would like to map button 8 to left click, and button 9 to right click.  It appears xinput only lets me have 1 button per action type.

Is there a way to have button 1 and 8 both mapped to the same action along with 3 and 9?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't understand xinput design.  The following gives the behavior specified above.  ID of the mouse is 10.

xinput set-button-map 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 10 11 12 13